# Match Arm saying type mismatch

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, match

I have followed the Rust Book Chapter 2 to write the following program.

Here, I really liked the `match` keyword
#1

```
use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess A Number");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
    
    loop {
        println!("Enter the Number:");

        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Unable to Read the Input");

        //The following snippet of code
        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Not A Number, Try Again");
                continue;
            }
        };
        //end

        println!("Your Guess {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too Big"),
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too Small"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You Win");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And so I used `match` statement in doing a question given at the end of Chapter 3.

#2:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the number:");

    let mut term = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut term)
        .expect("\nFailed to Read");
  
    //The following snippet
    let term: u32 = match term.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Input Not a Number");
            continue;
        }
    };
    //end
}
```

But in #2, the compiler gives the following error:

```
 mismatched types

 expected `u32`, found `()`
```

And the following error

```
`continue` outside of a loop
```

I really don't understand why I am getting this error. Probably a newbie mistake.

Please, show me my error.

Thanks

**Editor**: VS Code

**Extensions**: rust-lang, rust-analyzer

Comment: You probably mean `return`, rather than `continue`. The latter can only be used in loops, exactly as described in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mismatched type error is because the type of `term` is explicitly specified as u32, and the first match arm is implicitly returning u32, but the second match arm is returning the unit value `()`.  There are only a few ways to exit a match expression, and here you will either need to return a u32 (which you probably don't want to do), or you can call return to exit from the function, or call panic!() to terminate the program.  The continue keyword can only be used inside of a loop, but not matches.  There is no equivalent to `break` from C switch statements unfortunately.

If you didn't want to return from the function right away, you could rewrite this to store the Result<u32, _> returned by parse(), and then use an if let statement to check for an error, but it would likely be better to make a function that can be returned from, which has the match statement in it, and then calling that function from main().  Since the Rust compiler uses aggressive optimizations (at least when compiled with --release), it might actually eliminate the function entirely, so using lots of functions doesn't have the same penalty as it would in C